# Fit 8 frame layouts in a linear layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I have an application where I need to fit 8 frame layouts inside a linear layout in the below format :

```
                ----------------------
                   1     |     2
               ----------------------
                   3     |     4
                ----------------------
                   5     |     6
               ----------------------
                   7     |     8
```

The XML file i created for the same is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
          >


     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/My_Container_1_ID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"


         >

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/My_Container_2_ID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"

      >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>





     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/My_Container_3_ID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_weight="1"

         >
    </FrameLayout>

     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/My_Container_4_ID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_weight="1"

       >
    </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/My_Container_5_ID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"


         >

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/My_Container_6_ID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"

      >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>




      <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/My_Container_7_ID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"


         >

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/My_Container_8_ID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"

      >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Irrespective of what I do, the layout do not align properly and sometime the images in one frame layout overwrite the other layouts.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add layout_weight = 1 to all four of you inner Linear Layout whose orientation is horizontal. Add match_parent and other attributes to get the required result I have done one here add to rest of them

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000">


     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:baselineAligned="false" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/My_Container_1_ID"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/My_Container_2_ID"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    ....
    ....
    ....


</LinearLayout>
```

If you add similar attributes to other 3 layout it will work as expected. Notice the 0dp it is written as suggested by Android when using weights. It will work but you should consider using GridLayout that comes in support v7 library. The reason being the above approach contains nested weights which is bad for performance plus this thing won't scroll. So on smaller devices expect weird result.

Comment: Works Brilliant !! Yes, Even I was thinking of using a Grid Layout as like you mentioned, its giving weird results on smaller devices. Thanks a ton for the help!